# У меня выскакивает ошибка

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Когда делал свой проект внезапно появилась ошибка в разделе, где изменять дизайн(я новичок :)). вот и ошибка - Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme
UPD код:

```
package com.talk.talktools;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.Locale;

public class main extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{private Button button;
    private EditText editText;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private TextToSpeech mTTS;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_ttsactivity);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String text = editText.getText().toString();
                mTTS.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        mTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    int result = mTTS.setLanguage(new Locale("ru"));

                    if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                            || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                        Log.e("TTS", "Language not supported");
                    } else {
                        button.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("TTS", "Initialization failed");
                }
            }
        });

        View.OnClickListener Oclbutton = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = editText.getText().toString();
                mTTS.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

            }
        };

        button.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) Oclbutton);
    }

    public main(FloatingActionButton fab) {
        this.fab = fab;
        setTitle("Talk&Tools");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.ttsactivity, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".main"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_ttsactivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:text="@string/text_to_speech"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/text_to_speech"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Видимо, такой стиль у вас в стилях не прописан. Пропишите или удалите строчку `android:style="..."`

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните вопрос кодом, где возникает ошибка. [**Почему это нужно**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). Спасибо.

Comment: я бы прописал строчку android:style, но я к сожалению, не знаю, где ее писать и что в ней писать, извините, что тупой

Comment: Если ошибка у вас в "разделе, где изменять дизайн", покажите код оттуда (xml)

Answer (score 0):

Видимо речь шла о `SDK-28`, там такое наблюдается постоянно. И не только у новичков которые первый раз студию ставят, а постоянно при создании нового проекта.

*Варианты решения:*

1)Остаться на  `SDK-28` но понизить `Android SDK Build-tools` до `28.0.0-alpha1` (если она у Вас `28.0.0-alpha3`).
2)Если первый вариант не помог, то перейти на  `SDK-27`.

У меня например отлично работает

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 27
        ...
    }

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    ...
}
```